# Touchpad (Mouse), wifi/ethernet, and speaker does not work after upgrading kernel

Tags: 20.04, kernel, internet, touchpad, speakers

I have a local machine on ubuntu (20.04, ), recently I have upgraded kernel version 5.15.0-60 generic, and after rebooting, both my Wi-Fi and Ethernet and touchpad mouse does not work. I did following command to see the ip address of them, instead of enlp.... stays br-4a..... and description is (NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP). I thought that I could download kernel from official repo and send it to removable device and install it manually but I kind of have a doubt that it is proper way to solve this problem. I also noticed that speaker does not work, it shows as a "Dummy output".
Are there any ways to roll back, to previous kernel version?

P.S.
When I start my local machine, log showed up with starting services, and one task failed

`[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module See 'systemctl status virtualbox.service' for details`

I looked it up and it showed:

```
virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module  
Loaded: loaded(/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
Docs: man: systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 2471 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  

systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
virtualbox[2471]:  *Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
virtualbox[2471]:  *No suitable module for running kernel found*
virtualbox[2471]:   ...fail!
systemd[1]: virtual.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
```

Comment: Seems you question might be missing an important detail or two. Is it a VM? Please edit the question and add all the details.

Comment: @David, It is not VM, this distro installed on my local machine, it is not installed on a virtual environment.

Comment: From your question have you looked at what it tells you to look at? Use edit and add it to you question. [FAILED] Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module See 'systemctl status virtualbox.service' for details

Comment: @David, updated)

Comment: I solved this problem, the problem was kernel version that I upgraded. I rolled back and use older version, and it worked)